# How do I use ghost to restore a hard drive image while omitting certain partitions?

Tags: ghost

I am using Symantec Ghost (version 8). I recently created an image of a hard drive that has 4 partitions: System (300 MB), C: (100GB), Recovery (14GB), and Tools (5GB). I would like to restore this image to a larger hard drive, and omit the "Recovery" and "Tools" partitions. I would like the "C" partition to take the place of these and whatever remaining space is left on the drive. I would also like to keep the system partition.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have found Symantec documentation the "Clone" switch here: http://service1.symantec.com/SUPPORT/sunset-c2002kb.nsf/0/58158dc00b74f1b185256ee500610be3?OpenDocument&seg=en&lg=en&ct=us but I am confused on which combination of switches to use.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use command-line switches for this. You can use the GUI to clone from a file to a partition. I don't have Ghost 8 in front of me, but if I recall properly you may have to pre-create the partitions before you clone into them.

Since the order of the partitions is such that the ones you don't want are at the end of the disk there's always the option to restore the image as-is, delete the extra partitions you don't want, then grow the "C:" partition to fill the remainder of the space. You can do this inside the OS in Windows Vista and newer Windows versions, or by booting a Windows Vista or newer setup DVD and using DISKPART to extend the volume (since pre-Windows Vista versions won't let you extend the booted system volume).

Comment: Should be as Evan Anderson says.  Can be done in GUI and you should be able to resize in the GUI.

Comment: It actually worked out best to just restore the image as is, pop the hard drive out, and delete and extend partitions via disk management in Windows 7. I wasn't aware Window 7 added that functionality in disk management. I can now just reimage without the partitions removed.

Comment: With the partitions removed*